# A theorem or result relating the probability of occurence of outliers to population size

Tags: probability, outliers

I was wondering if there is a theorem or a result that relates the size of the population to the probability of the occurrence of outliers of various degrees, relating the z-score to the size of the population and whether the relation is linear or not. Thanks.

Comment: There couldn't possibly be any theorem about such a vague topic.  Let's start with "outlier:" what does that mean to you?  What assumptions do you make about the population?  What do you mean by "relation"?  We'll need you to include these details and more in your question in order to answer it.

Comment: I know my question is vague, I don't have the stats background to be able to use precise language unfortunately. Outlier is vague but obviously any result pertaining to extreme values can define it however they want. I thought I was able to communicate the gist of what I am after. Even if anyone can point me in a general direction to be able to read about probability of extreme values of a normal distribution or large deviations from the mean and the relation of this probability with the population sizes in general, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Please edit your post to provide the specifics of the question you have in mind.  That's essential here on CV, because we can't really handle vague general questions in this format.

Comment: How do I delete it?

Comment: You don't need to--just edit it by clicking the "Edit" link beneath the text.

Comment: But like I said I don't have enough knowledge to specify it really, sorry. I did some reading, and it might be a more complicated issue than imagined, studied in areas like extreme value theory and large deviation theory; will skim through some texts to see if there's anything about population size's impact on extreme values in there.